# Failed to install PrimeNg specific version in Angular Project

Tags: angular, primeng

I have created an Angular Project and the version is 12.0.0. Now I would like to install the PrimeNG library in my angular project. I would like to install a **specific version of PrimeNG 12.2.5**. So I have used the below NPM commands.

```
    npm install primeng@12.2.5 --save
           OR
    npm install primeng@12.2.5-lts  --save
```

But in both cases I found the below errors:

> npm ERR! code ETARGET npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for
> primeng@12.2.5. npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your
> dependencies are requesting npm ERR! notarget a package version that
> doesn't exist.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> C:\Users\Nasir\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-04-06T08_32_43_396Z-debug-0.log

Can anyone help me to find a solution of this error?

Answer (score 0):

there is no version called (12.2.5) but if you want to install a specific version you can go to primeng versions tap https://www.npmjs.com/package/primeng?activeTab=versions  and select the version and it will generate the npm command for you